# refresh token with retrofit in android kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I try to send the refresh token to the server when the access token expires and receive a new accesss token, but my code does not work properly.

refresh token class

```
class RefreshToken(): Authenticator {
    override fun authenticate(route: Route?, responsee: Response): Request? {
        if (responsee.code == 401) {
            lateinit var loginRepository: LoginRepository
            lateinit var bodyRefresh: BodyRefresh
            lateinit var access: StoreAccess //datastore for save token
            lateinit var newAccess: String

                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
                    access.getUserRefresh().collect {
                        val refresh = it.toString()
                        bodyRefresh.refresh = refresh
                        val response = loginRepository.RefreshAccess(bodyRefresh)
                        if (response.isSuccessful) {
                            access.saveUserRefresh(response.body()?.access.toString())
                            newAccess = response.body()?.access.toString()
                        }
                    }
                }
            
                return responsee.request.newBuilder().header("Authorization", "Bearer $newAccess.toString()")
                    .build()
            } else {
                return responsee.request
            }
        }
}
```

api service

```
 @POST("token/refresh/")
    suspend fun refreshAcssec(@Body refresh: BodyRefresh): Response<ResponseAcces>
```

Comment: You need to be more specific what is failing. "my code does not work properly" just leads everyone guessing what error you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using runBlocking{ } instead of CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch.
It's working for me, but I don't know if is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's ok, because Authenticator and Interceptor will run on another thread

check this

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73258302/19652639)

Comment: Even though the question isn't really clear, this answer does not provide any answers at all